# Set-Cookie header in Glassfish-5: folding several cookies in one header not working on Firefox (https + HTTP/2.0)

Tags: java, http, servlets, cookies, glassfish-5

I noticed that Glassfish-5 web server sends responses with only one `Set-Cookie` header, which contains several cookies. When I looking with firebug, I can see that they are separated by unknown character. Anyway - the Firefox reads only the first cookie. How to configure Glassfish5 to send several Set-Cookie headers - one for each cookie? [rfc6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) states that:

> 3. Overview
>     ...    
>    Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into    a single header field.  The usual mechanism for
>    folding HTTP headers    fields (i.e., as defined in [RFC2616]) might
>    change the semantics of    the Set-Cookie header field because the
>    %x2C (",") character is used    by Set-Cookie in a way that conflicts
>    with such folding.
>     ...

Also [here](http://www.openradar.me/15933483) it is stated:

> When sending an HTTP Response with multiple cookies, CFHTTPMessage
> combines the cookies into a comma-separated list under a single
> "Set-Cookie" HTTP header. (This is referred to as
> "set-cookie-folding".)
>
> Set-cookie-folding is NOT supported on Google Chrome, Firefox, and
> Internet Explorer. Each of those browsers will completely ignore every
> cookie after the first comma, rendering CFHTTPMessage completely
> useless for handling HTTP responses with multiple cookies in any
> browser other than Safari (which supports cookie-folding).

This is how the response looks on firebug:
[image]
Two cookies are joint by unknown character. As I noticed - other servers like Apache splits multiple cookies in one `Set-Cookie` header by new line character.

**I've noticed that this happens only on HTTPS connections.**

Also, I've opened an issue on Github [here](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22208).

Tried the same web application to run on Tomcat 9 web server - `Set-Cookie` header cookies are separated by new line character, it's working like expected...
[image]

The same response, but on Glassfish5, and again - cookies are joined by unknown character, and are not accepted by Firefox (just the first one):
[image]

In NetBeans IDE 8.2 HTTP Server Monitor I can see, that 2 cookies are sent - it looks ok:
[image]

Once again on FireFox - 2 cookies in one Set-Cookie header:
[image]

Received only one - and the value is not correct... :
[image]

The same on Firefox Developer Edition:
[image]

Totally confused..

Glassfish 5 uses Grizzly Framework 2.4.0 - I think sources available in [grizzly-http-servlet-2.4.0-sources.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http-servlet/2.4.0/grizzly-http-servlet-2.4.0-sources.jar) - but can not find a code piece where the cookies are joined together in one line..

I can confirm now that it is related only to HTTP/2.0 protocol, tested on firefox by enabling/disabling `network.http.spdy.enabled.http2` in `about:config`. On HTTP/1.1 via HTTPS cookies are set as expected.

Comment: could you please tell me the char code?

Comment: Dang, I just realized you're using *Firebug*... With HTTP/2... Quoting getfirebug.com: *The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer. We invite you to use the Firefox DevTools instead*. Okay there's Firebug.next, but... Do you still see this strange character with Firefox DevTools' Network tab? And how do you observe that only the first cookie works?

Comment: Yes, it is the same on Firefox Developer Ed. I can check the cookies received by Tools -> Options -> Remove individual cookies.

Comment: Also noticed that NetBeans IDE 8.2 HTTP Server Monitor shows request protocol HTTP/2.0, so it means it supports HTTP/2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer need that custom nucleus-grizzly-all.jar.  The issue has been released as part of the most recent Glassfish 5.0 nightlies and the most recent promoted build.

There were two different issues as I tracked the actual fix with a Grizzly issue and used the GlassFish issue for integration of Grizzly.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>In a series of comments that we deleted since, I pointed that the weird responses were all http2, and gave directions to disable it server-side, as a work-around. Now to make room for other constructive comments (or answers) we deleted the old ones, and I rehashed them as a separate answer below.</sub>

It seems Grizzly's http2 filters are misbehaving (well let's assume that for a moment). Your Firefox screenshots are showing `HTTP/2.0`. NetBeans server monitor works OK likely because it does not support http2, so your server falls back to `HTTP/1.1` in that case. <sub>(Edit: that was just a supposition, and a more recent comment hints that it *might* support http2...)</sub>

Grizzly supports HTTP2 since 2.4.0 but you have to [explicitly enable it](https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/http2.html)... and GlassFish [does that by default](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/5.0-b19/nucleus/grizzly/config/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/config/dom/Http.java#L99).

> How to configure Glassfish5 to send several Set-Cookie headers - one for each cookie?

While the Glassfish/Grizzly team works on [fixing the (apparent) bug](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22208), you can disable http2 in GlassFish as a work-around.

Assuming your HTTPS listener is `http-listener-2` you can do this from the command line:

```
asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.htt‌​p.http2-enabled=fals‌​e
```

As far as I know this setting is not documented yet, I inferred the command above from [this @Attribute in source code](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/5.0-b19/nucleus/grizzly/config/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/config/dom/Http.java#L493) (and followed it through the code until [`GenericGrizzlyListener`](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/5.0-b19/nucleus/grizzly/config/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/config/GenericGrizzlyListener.java)). In addition, it seems that attribute is not exposed in the admin console so I see no other way than using `asadmin set` as above (please note the "Version" attribute is a [distinct](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/5.0-b19/nucleus/grizzly/config/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/config/dom/Http.java#L329) setting).

<sub>I based my research on "latest promoted build" (b19 at that time, "latest nightly" would be b20). Links to GitHub point to b19.</sub>

Comment: I can confirm that `asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.htt‌​p.http2-enabled=fals‌​e` is working, so this is a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is now solved by professional glassfish team - we should change the file `nucleus-grizzly-all.jar` file with new one - available [here](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22208#issuecomment-322931591) at GitHub. Once again - many thanks to glassfish developer team!

Comment: Ah, cool. So I think the problem was [here in EncoderUtils](https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/blob/33342e0858ec365424d7819bc3972d4fbaf1d629/modules/http2/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/http2/EncoderUtils.java#L287), the pesky character was a null character (`\u0000`), and the fixing commit is [here](https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/commit/a4196e096e34dd16988cc0283e9eb6de598713f2), (although the comment references another bug in the grizzly issues base, but perhaps it actually fixed several).